# Instantiate uses a lot of CPU resources, how to switch to Pooling?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a method which instantiates a lot of objects with this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(player.position.x+30f, player.position.x+80f), Random.Range(player.position.y, player.position.y+40), 0);  
    Instantiate(prefabs[Random.Range(0, 15)], position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Based on gameplay this loop runs let's say every 5-10 seconds. (based on checking some parameters in `Update()`

After some time I use `gameObject.Destroy()` on not needed objects. And here comes the problem:

1. On `Instantiate` I see 70% CPU usage in Profiler
2. On `Destroy` I see 10-20% CPU usage in Profiler
3. Sometimes `Destroy` and `Instantiate` methods would run at the same time causing CPU throttle.

Need to say that I'm targeting Mobile. The FPS is okay, but when testing the game, the mobile phone gets hot in a minute. I am really sure that is not how I should do this. I've read about polling but not sure how to reproduce it based on this code.

I am testing on Huawei Ascend G600, but I guess it's not the phones problem because Profiler shows the same high CPU usage on the desktop too.

Comment: To make object pooling you have to disclose what exactly you are doing in your game. For example, when do you have to instantiate a new GameObject? When do you destroy it? About how many GameObjects you instantiate and destroy are in the scene at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using [Spawning Pool by John Johnson](http://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/59409). Very easy implementation:

```
GameObject obj = SpawningPool.createFromCache(""+Random.Range(0, 15))
```

All prefabs are atached to SpawningPool object and are accesed via key name.
Instead of `Destroy()` I am now using `SpawningPool.ReturnToCache(gameObject)`
Totally recommend, CPU usage is reduced dramatically.